# <script async> not working in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

script async not working:

```
    <h1>Welcome#index</h1>

<script async>
     alert('hello World');
     alert('here we go');
</script>

<p>Find me in app/views/welcome/index.html.erb</p>
```

When page loading i see only header, can't understand why < p > loading only after script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`async` attribute works with external script only   Specifies that the script is executed asynchronously (only for external scripts)

Uses : If the async attribute is set on an external script (one with src=), browsers that support it will download that script in the background without blocking the rest of the content on the page. The script will execute whenever it is finished downloading.

source http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_script.asp

Comment: ok, but if i add code in asset javascript is this would be work correct? and if that would be work correct how i must do it?